# PHP Post after Ajax returns values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, undefined

For some reason a `POST` variable from my `form` is always empty. Here's my code...
I have a bootstrap select which returns information which I display upon selecting a new item from the dropdown (select).

Code:

```
$(function() {


    $("#shiftsDD").change(function(){
        var selectedItemId = $('#shiftsDD option:selected').val();  

        $.post('/step/services/shiftInfo.php', { shiftID : selectedItemId }, function(res){
          $("#shiftCard").show();
          var jsonRes = $.parseJSON(res);
           $("#address").html(jsonRes[0]);
           $("#duties").html(jsonRes[1]);
           $("#employer").html(jsonRes[4]);
           $("#payRate").html(jsonRes[5]);
           $("#theShiftID").html(jsonRes[6]);
           console.log(res);

        });
    });

});
```

All of those values from the jsonRes array are assigned in here:

```
<form role="form" name="cardForm" method="POST">
<div class="card" id="shiftCard">
Employer:
<h3 id="employer">Test Employer</h3><br>
Address:
<h3 id="address">Test Address</h3><br>
Duties include:
<h3 id="duties">Test duties</h3><br>
 Pay rate:
<h3 id="payRate">Test PayRate</h3><br>
<h5 id="theShiftID" name="myShiftID"></h5>
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-green-solid" name="shiftsBtn">Accept work</button>
</div>
</form>
```

I've tried lots of things but I am new to ajax and not a pro in PHP so I don't know why:

```
 if (isset($_POST['shiftsBtn'])) {

$theId = $_POST['myShiftID'];
...
```

`myShiftID` is always empty

ShiftsDD select code:

```
<select name="shiftsDD" id="shiftsDD" class="form-control form-control-45">
<option value="0">Select a shift</option>
<?php
   $theQuery = "
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(StartTime,  '%d/%b/%Y' ) AS ShiftDate, ShiftID,ShiftTitle,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime) AS ShiftDuration, ROUND(PayRate,2) as PayRate FROM Shifts;
   ";
 $result = $DBH->query($theQuery);
 $result->execute();

   while($r = $result->fetch()) {
 $theDuration = $r['ShiftDuration'] / 60;

 echo "<option value='" . $r['ShiftID'] ."'>[". $r['ShiftDate'] . "] " . $r['ShiftTitle'] . " (Hours: " . $theDuration . ")</option>"; 
}

?>
</select>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and look at your console.

Comment: added it and i get no errors in console. i receive and display the value i want from ajax but when i press the submit button i get that the post variable is empty (undefined index) and  u can see the above code seems fine

Comment: `<h5 id="theShiftID" name="myShiftID"></h5>` - Far as I know, H elements does not account as an (POST-able) input. You may be able to do this with a DOM but not the way you're doing it now. *"undefined index"* that I knew you'd get that which is why I asked you to use error reporting.

Comment: Can you please post the form html please.

Comment: @Brett I did in my question. Fred, got a suggestion why `$("#theShiftID").html(jsonRes[6]);` doesnt put my variable in my h5 if I change it to an input text? i've tried that

Comment: I mean the html that contains the element  $("#shiftsDD"). I want to know where it's getting the value it's sending to your php script

Comment: Oh okay, I added the code. But as you can see the whole ajax depends on the ID coming from there and as I told you, the response is correct from Ajax and it even returns back the `ID` that was selected. I can display it in an `h5` but it can't send a Post variable i guess. Tried changing to `input type text` but then ajax can't set its value.

Comment: Oh ok i see the issue. I will add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so you need to change the form to match below. Have removed the elements you don't need to change. Note changing the h5 to an input.

```
<form role="form" name="cardForm" method="POST">
<div class="card" id="shiftCard">
<input id="theShiftID" name="myShiftID" value="" /><br />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-green-solid" name="shiftsBtn">Accept work</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Then once you've made the form changes, you need to change your js from .html() to .val()

```
$(function() {
    $("#shiftsDD").on('change', function(){
        var selectedItemId = $(this).val();  

        $.post('/step/services/shiftInfo.php', { shiftID : $(this).val() }, function(res){
          $("#shiftCard").show();
          var jsonRes = $.parseJSON(res);
          $("#theShiftID").val(jsonRes[6]);    
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Wow, I already tried changing it to input instead of h5 but I didn't know to receive the value I'd have to use `.val` instead. Now it works fine indeed. Thank you!